# How Do You Install Missing sass-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

Hi new to stackoverflow and Ruby on Rails in general. I'm following the Kevin Skoglund Ruby on Rails 3 Essential Training online tutorial and I'm having trouble starting out. I'm trying to boot WEBrick but each time I try I get this error:

C:\Users\Matt\Documents\Sites\simple_cms>rails server
Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 5.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources l
isted in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

What do I do to install this missing sass-rails gem, so I can boot WEBrick?

Comment: what have your Gemfile? you have experience with sass? do you really want use sass?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run `bundle install` in your terminal, or command line, as the output suggests.

```
$ bundle install
```

If that fails, run:

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Doesn't work: Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: Do you have the rake command available? `which rake`,`rake --version`